Migration Oracle Form 12c to Oracle APEX 20.2
I need some help I use Oracle Form and Reports 12c.I created allots of Forms and now I migrate these forms to oracle apex. Someone could help how do I migrate them? There is a menu of migration oracle forms in apex 20.2. I try but nothing happen.
Migrate Oracle forms to Oracle APEX

The only way you can "migrate" Forms to APEX is to create your APEX apps from scratch.  You cannot convert Forms to APEX.
That said, why are you wasting your time doing this?
